# Hosting a webservice that uses Excel spreadsheets for its implementation

Tags: excel, web-services

I need to turn an app developed in Python and relying heavily on complex Excel spreadsheets into a webservice. The spreadsheets that make-up the app are used to store data as well as algorithms.

The service will have a simple API to start-off with, allowing the user to upload an Excel spreadsheet with their own data and download the results calculated by the service.

How would I go about hosting such an app? I've seen plenty of references to consuming a webservice from Excel but not to use Excel as part of a webservice.

My initial thoughts were to look for a service provider that could rent me a Windows VM on which I'd install Excel (with our license) and somehow deploy the webservice. But I'm wondering if anything more streamlined might exist.

Disclaimer: I'm a newbie; I've solid experience developing webservices (SOAP & REST) for embedded machines, but this will be my first hosted service.

Comment: M365 has an excel API...you are reinventing the wheel if you are figuring out how to host it on your own, try to use Microsoft API or figure out how to migrate the data to a DB.   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/excel-concept-overview

Comment: you should be able to access the spreadsheet from anywhere on the internet. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/excel-services-rest-api